# Adding an xml node to site during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

during PageLoad() I find a Control with:

```
this.FindControl("ViewMenuDiv");
```

Now I have to add a child node into this control in the XML-Context

So the node

```
<div ID="ViewMenuDiv" runat="server">
</div>
```

will became:

```
<div ID="ViewMenuDiv" runat="server">
   <mySpecialUnknownNode/>
</div>
```

mySpecialUnknownNode is provided by a dll. I can get it as a string. Though this is NOT a Literal, it can be a picture, a button or something other...

how can I achieve that?

Comment: `ViewMenuDiv.InnerHtml = nodeValue;`?

Comment: @ (ViewMenuDiv.InnerHtml = nodeValue;? – JLRishe ): MSVS 2012 tells me, that the Class "Control" does not have a Property named "InnerHTML"...

Comment: Have you tried acessing the `ViewMenuDiv` directly (without using `FindControl`)? If it's part of the page itself (as opposed to being part of a User Control or something like that), you should be able to access it directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Yes I can access it this way. Now I found MANY other reasons, why the program does not do, what it should... I have to check them first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should be able to assign the HTML to the div's `InnerHtml` property, without first retrieving it using `FindControl`:

```
ViewMenuDiv.InnerHtml = nodeValue;
```

This should be possible for any HTML element in your page that has `runat="server"` and an ID.